# Abrir aplicación de WhatsApp desde VB6

Tags: vb6, whatsapp

buenos días, mi consulta radica en si existe algo semejante a lo que se hace en C#:

```
var process = $"whatsapp://send?phone=54{numero}&text={mensaje}";
Process.Start(process);
```

Pero desde VB6, ¿Existe algo como eso?
Lo que quiero lograr es abrir la aplicación de WhatsApp de Windows y que se abra en el número asignado con un mensaje predeterminado. En C# funciona pero en VB6 no he encontrado algo que me indique que se puede

Comment: La ejecución de procesos desde VB6 se hace mediante "Shell". No creo que puedas abrir la App de Whatsapp (supongo que hablamos de Windows 10), usando "Shell" en VB6. Aunque no soy experto en esto, podría haber alguna forma de hacerlo. Pero VB6 ya está bastante desactualizado. En mi opinión podrías usarlo para consumir algún otro servicio escrito con un lenguaje (framework) más actual (C#, como mencionas) y que sea éste último el que lance la llamada para abrir Whatsapp. Es sólo una idea.

Comment: Como mencionas se hace con "Shell". Estuve probando, copié el .exe de WhatsApp en mi disco C pero nada ha sucedido al presionar el botón desde VB6. Es como que sabe que está pero no pasa nada. Piensa unos segundos como si quisiera ejecutar algo pero no pasa más nada. El inconveniente es que debo usar VB6, la otra alternativa es usar una url , que se abra en cualquier navegador y bueno desde ahí que se abra la app pero es algo que prefiero evitar. Lo ideal sería que se abra la app desde un botón en un chat determinado @MauricioContreras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguí la solución gracias a SO Inglés por lo que dejo el resultado:

Lo primero es declarar la función `ShellExecute` con sus respectivos parámetros:

```
Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" _
                    Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
                    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                    ByVal lpOperation As String, _
                    ByVal lpFile As String, _
                    ByVal lpParameters As String, _
                    ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
                    ByVal nShowCmd As Long) _
                    As Long

Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
```

Y luego llamarla desde el botón:

```
Private Sub btnWhats_Click()
    Dim texto As String
    texto = "Esto es una prueba"
    ShellExecute Me.hwnd, "Open", "whatsapp://send?phone=543513333333&text=" & texto, "", "", SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
End Sub
```

Esto realmente funciona, espero que le sirva a alguien en el futuro